# Custom ClassLoader, how to use?

Tags: java, classloader, dynamic-class-loaders

I am trying to use a custom class loader to load all the dependencies needed for the application. I've implemented the customerClassLoader following the site: https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/03/java-handmade-classloader-isolation.html

However, I dont understand how to tell my application to use the custom classLoader whenever needed.

For instance: Lets say, I have a method to make http request like below. How can I tell the application to use the custom classLoader to load the required jars?

```
private HttpResponse get() {
    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Java uses `ClassLoader` implicitly when you use `new`, `import` keyword, the jvm will use the current class's classloader to load the dependent classes, so you can use the custom classloader to load a `bootstrap` class explicitly by using `classloader.loadclass`, and the `bootstrap` just runs a method belonging to your target class instance. An example follows.

There is a class `Target` that depends on the class `DateFormatter` which is included in the `spring-context`, and has a method named `start`.

```
import org.springframework.format.datetime.DateFormatter;

public class Target {

private static DateFormatter dateFormatter;

public void start(){
    System.out.println(this.getClass().getClassLoader());
    dateFormatter=new DateFormatter();
    System.out.println(dateFormatter);
    }
}
```

Next, we compile and package the above code as a jar named `target.jar`, which is stored at `D:\\test\\target.jar`.

Next, we declare a class `BootStrap` in another jar that will call the method `start` of `Target` instance. The `BootStrap` class will dynamically load the `target.jar` and `spring-context` jar files by the same `classloader` which is a `URLClassLoader` instance. Because of this, the method `start` in `Target` instance can access the `DateFormatter` class that is defined in `spring-context`.

```
public class BootStrap {


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    URL url = new URL("http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/groups/public/org/springframework/spring-context/4.3.1.RELEASE/spring-context-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar?spm=0.0.0.0.kG1Pdw&file=spring-context-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar");
    URL url2= (new File("D:\\test\\target.jar").toURI().toURL());
    URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{url,url2});
    Class<?> clz = classLoader.loadClass("com.zhuyiren.Target");
    Object main = clz.newInstance();
    Method test = clz.getMethod("start");
    test.invoke(main);
    }
}
```

Finally, run the `BootStrap` main method. There are two important thing:

1. The `BootStrap` class and `Target` class don't belong to a same jar file.
2. The `target.jar` is not stored in `CLASSPATH` path.

These 2 point can make sure that the `AppClassLoader` can not find and load the `Target` class. Because of the mechanism of class loader, jvm will use the custom load the `Target`. Of course, you can guarantee it by changing the `URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{url,url2});` to `URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{url, url2}, ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getParent());`

And we can see the result:

```
java.net.URLClassLoader@e9e54c2
org.springframework.format.datetime.DateFormatter@4dd8dc3
```

That means we can access the `DateFormatter` instance which is defined in `spring-context` jar file successfully, while the `spring-context` is not stored in `CLASSPATH`, but we are using the custom clasloader to load and use it.