# How to replace a class at runtime?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have 2 classes. I want to replace one, class `A` so that ANY instance of it will actually behave like class `B`.

```
class A {
    fun test() = "a"
}

class B { 
    fun test() = "b"
}
```

I was trying to use the `ClassLoader` to do this but I couldn't get the system to call `MyClassLoader`.

```
class MyClassLoader() : ClassLoader() {

    @Throws(ClassNotFoundException::class)
    override fun loadClass(name: String): Class<*>? {
        if (name == "com.myapp.A") {
            return B::class.java
        } else return super.loadClass(name)
    }
}
```

This has to happen at compile time or runtime because I cannot manually replace every instance of `A` for `B`. (This is a minimalist example of the problem). `A` cannot be removed, this is a requirement.

So how do I attach `MyClassLoader` so that the system uses it?

I tried: `Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(MyClassLoader())` but the `MyClassLoader` doesn't get called.

Comment: Why do you load `A` in the first place? Why not just replace `A` with `B` in the entire code?

Comment: Unfortunately `A` is there and cannot be removed.

Comment: Reads like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/351454) to me. The ability to choose an implementation separately from the method definitions, at runtime, is what **interfaces** were invented to solve.

Comment: It is not XY problem. I simplified the problem for the question. The problem is I need to change the class loader for mine.

Comment: maybe [Custom ClassLoader, how to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45656836/85421) - just for Java

Comment: @user85421 close, but it didn't work

Comment: This is not the XY problem, so upvoted and developers needs more control over languages, if this question gets answered it will help the community in securing the java sources from reverse engineering too

Answer (score -3):

You can use the Factory design pattern. Depending on what kind of class instance you want you can load/return it at runtime from the Factory class static method.

Answer (score -3):

i do not know what it will use for but for low scale ,you can try to have only on object that contain the methods and properties of both classes 
like example

```
val classType2 = 1
class AB{
    fun testA() = "a"
    fun testB() = "b"
    val classType1 = 1 

   fun test() {
     if(classType1 ==1){testA()}
     else{testB()}    
   }

}
```

you can add fun to change the  class type or,

if you want to change all instances at the same replace   classType1 with classType2 at if contition  then change value of classType2.

i hope that